# Export specific columns in PrimeNG table

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to export a table to CSV. I want to export only specific columns. I try this code in my HTML:

```
 <button type="button"  (click)="myTable.exportCSV(['craNotValidated'])" ></button>
```

But when executing, I get this error:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: sorry, but without more details, we can't answer this question. what does the exportCSV function do?

Comment: i have takin it from the official doc, exportCSV() is the default function to export data from table which is in my case 'myTable'